# White space on top of page (Firefox Specific)

Tags: css, html, firefox

I'm getting a big whitespace on top of my page only in firefox. I tried to inspect all elements and can't find anything wrong with it. I also checked for uncollapsing margin but can't find any.

I'm using HTML5, modernzr and jquery.

Website URL : http://devvanickcom.vanickurl.com/

[image: Screenshot of page]

Comment: Weird.  The problem went away when I simply clicked on the `overall-wraper` `div` in the Firefox DOM Inspector.

Comment: It has something to do with the `position:absolute` style in the logo class.  If it is disabled in Firebug the gap goes away.

Comment: For me the gap went away after clicking on the wrapper `div` in the DOM Inspector.  Then no matter how many times I hard refresh the page, I cannot get the problem to come back.  I have to open a brand new window and load the URL there to see it again.

Comment: It appears to be due to your `<hr class="clear">` inside `<div id="contact-toggler-wrapper">`. Removing it fixes the problem. I can theorize about it interfering but I honestly have no idea what the *exact* cause of Firefox's display issue is with that element. Probably something to do with your method of using text-indent...

Comment: If I (1) move the anchor element with the logo class inside of the div element with the contact-toggler-wrapper class (just above the clear div) and (2) remove the position:absolute style from the contact-toggler-wrapper class things start to look better to me.

Comment: I noticed that when the header tag is changed to a div the gap disappears. (It breaks the nav layout, and the semantics, so not a solution.)

Comment: @thisgeek, this is because the margin applied to `header nav` is no longer applied. See my answer below.

Comment: The link is dead and no source is provided.

Comment: As of 7.28.22 this happens when opening inspector in FF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a Firefox bug ([#451791](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791)). The margin collapse is done wrong. It collapses through `hr.clear`, as it has no height/padding/border, resulting in 90px of margin above `hr.clear`, but it also applies the correct margin of 90px below the floating element.

Any fix that would ordinarily prevent margin collapse will stop this behavior. For example, setting `hr.clear { height: 1px }` pushes everything back up, but it also shifts things down a pixel, which is undesirable. An interesting fix is to set `header { padding-top: .001em }`. This won't add enough padding to actually shift things visually, but it counts enough to prevent the margin from collapsing beyond the boundaries of `header`.

Alternatively, you could just rewrite your code to avoid this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `position` property in the `#logo` class of your css, set it to:

`position: relative`, the class would look like:

```
#logo {
    background: url("/Content/images/sprite.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

after that you need to change the `header nav` class, (margin was 90px on top)

```
header nav {
    margin: 40px 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then just need to adapt it exactly the way you need it, it will look like this on firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's very bizarre. I guess the easiest and best way would be, like animuson said, to remove `<hr class="clear">` under `<div id="contact-toggler-wrapper">` . It did the trick without affecting the layout.