# White space on top of page - Firefox only - 1 page only

Tags: css, html, firefox

I get a big whitespace on top of my page only in firefox. The weird thing is that other pages of the website behave as expected. I inspected all elements and compared the code but couldn't find anything wrong with it.

the webpage is http://www.veema.co.uk

I have found another topic which is somewhat similar:
[White space on top of page (Firefox Specific)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747517/white-space-on-top-of-page-firefox-specific)
but didn't manage to get any answer for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

please add this css property , Its is easy solution Or  Please use clearfix http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid skeleton.css (line 211), and use clearfix properly

Answer (score 4):

Space is because of `margin-top: 60px;` on stylesheet **css/style.css** in line number 29.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Disabling the .spacer margin-top declaration in Firebug makes the space at the top of the page vanish. Shibin Ragh's observations are also valid points though.

Comment: Its ok but "spacer"  didnt call

Comment: @ShibinRagh there is script `<!-- /End 960 Container -->

        <div class="container clearfix spacer"></div>

        <!-- Footer -->` which we can't see on firebug as well as page source but I wonder firefox is showing the script when I first select the menus of the site and click on view selection source.

Comment: Ohh Yes (y) , You are right